# Input record does not contain <field> field in data fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-data-fusion

i am creating one pipeline from sql server instance in compute engine and i want to migrate this data to bigquery but in previews instance its all fine and i can to watch the rows without problem but when i run the deployment in datafusion the instance give me the next error

````
0:c.g.c.h.i.b.BigQueryFactory@76] - Creating BigQuery from given credential.
2021-05-24 21:22:28,967 - INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 0:c.g.c.h.i.b.BigQueryFactory@76] - Creating BigQuery from default credential.
2021-05-24 21:22:28,978 - INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 0:c.g.c.h.i.b.BigQueryFactory@76] - Creating BigQuery from given credential.
2021-05-24 21:22:28,991 - INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 0:c.g.c.h.i.b.o.ForwardingBigQueryFileOutputFormat@76] - Delegating functionality to 'AvroOutputFormat'.
2021-05-24 21:22:31,811 - ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task 0:o.a.s.u.Utils@91] - Aborting task  
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:** **Input record does not contain the DatabaseLogId field.** ```

what is your suggestion about this
````

Comment: Can you please attach complete stack trace and pipeline configurations?

Answer (score 0):

The column name must be the same in input and output when you simply use SQLServer Source --> BQ Table Sink.

e.g:

query source: select dt as **DatabaseLogId**

column in sink: data_base_log_id (will throw your exception)

column in sink: **DatabaseLogId** (OK)